# SSRS Date Parameter Allow Nulls but date picker is enabled

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, asp.net-mvc-5, reportviewer

Has anyone run into this problem with SSRS where you have the date parameter set to "allow null" and the default value is set to (NULL) but when you run the report from the web page the datepicker is enabled even though the Null is checked like below. Which allows the user to pick a date even though the Null box is checked. When I run it from the SSRS server or from VS in preview mode the datepicker is correctly disabled until the check box is un-checked. Is this a bug or something else?

I had to use the iframe as we incorporated the report viewer in a MVC5 environment so I had to add an aspx page inside a MVC5 with Iframe. I am also using the 14.0 control so I suspect all of these combinations may well be causing my problem.

Is there a workaround for this problem in the environment I had to setup?

Any help would be appreciated

[Date Picker Enabled Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws7Qb.jpg)

Comment: The Report Viewer control in aspx should be fine without adding the iframe. Have you tried that?

Comment: The only way I found to get the report viewer to work in MVC5 was by using an iframe.